# Is there a way to tell gradle to not use ".gradle" within the (root) project folder?

Tags: java, gradle

When gradle runs, it relies on creating a `.gradle` folder within the [project root](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:project_root) directory. gradle puts all sorts of information in there, for example its "file cache".

In user guide linked above mentions that the gradle **user** home location can be changed by using the `$GRADLE_USER_HOME` env variable. Now I am wondering if there is a way to do the same for the folder that gradle needs/wants in the project root?

---

Why? We build multiple different "products" out of the same source code, so our legacy backend verification build simply did call our own build tool **in parallel** on the same source folder. We changed the java build to gradle, but it turns out: multiple gradle daemons using the same "shared" project-root/.gradle simply doesn't work reliably, leading to well known `Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache` failures.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:project_root) you link to calls `.gradle` the "_project-specific cache directory_". The command-line has an [environment option](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#environment_options) named `--project-cache-dir` which "_specifies the project-specific cache directory_" and defaults to "_`.gradle` in the root project directory_". I believe that's what you're looking for, but I haven't tried it so I don't know for sure. Note I was looking at version 7.0.2 documentation.

Comment: @Slaw You are correct, this works. Feel free to turn your comment into an answer! (albeit it turns out that `buildSrc` has is own `gradle`, too, which makes things even more complicated).

Comment: You might be better off trying to get a single Gradle process to build all your products simultaneously (in parallel). There seems to [be support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_configuration_and_execution.html#sec:parallel_execution) for both parallel task execution and parallel project execution. But unfortunately, I'm again not very familiar with this side of Gradle. Nor do I know if your setup is compatible.

Comment: I know ... but the problem is that we "evolve" our legacy build ... by keeping the outer onion layer the same. This means our own build tool can either build the old way, or using gradle. And our "verfication build setup" is kept the same for now, and would need to be massively reworked in order to do the java builds separately in a different way. So, at least for now, we rather hope to simply get "multiple dockers, each running its *own* gradle" to work. But yes, we are kinda fighting the intended use case, and that's frustrating.